# Different definitions of Morrey and Campanato Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

The book by Giaquinta defines Campanato spaces using the seminorm:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega \\ 0<r<\text{diam}(\Omega)}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

our lecture on the other hand uses:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega\\ 0<r<1}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

and I have also seen the following definition used:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega \\ 0<r<\min(1,\text{diam}(\Omega))}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

and similar for the definition of the Morrey spaces and for the definition "of type A".

Are those definitions equivalent? Or when are they equivalent?

Comment: MO copy: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173634/different-definitions-of-morrey-and-campanato-spaces

Comment: Answered my own question on the MO copy: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173634/different-definitions-of-morrey-and-campanato-spaces/186636#186636

Comment: Maybe you could post here an answer (perhaps CW) with the link to the MO post and mentioning that it is answered there. See [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got an answer to the question meanwhile (answered myself here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173634/different-definitions-of-morrey-and-campanato-spaces):

> The difference between the choice of upper bound $r$ is mainly related
>   to the assumptions one requires about $\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is
>   bounded, one wishes to have $A$ scaling-invariant and therefore
>   chooses $r = diam(\Omega)$. But any other finite number would work as
>   well. Therefore the choice of $1$ in the other definition. If $\Omega$
>   is not bounded on the other hand, one takes just $1$ by convention.
>   The upper bound does therefore change $A$ but not the fact whether a
>   $A$ exists or not therefore the set is still of Typ-$A$.